# How to select other objects from a group? (Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have a group of multiple objects.
If I select one object from the group, then i use the method:  click="makeObj(event)"
And then the function:

```
protected function makeObj(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var targetObj:Object = event.currentTarget;
        }
```

But how to use all the other objects in the group except clicked (target)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put all your objects in an array and define a clicked property for each object

```
protected function makeObj(event:MouseEvent):void
{
      //in case you want to deselect all the other objects when one
      //object is clicked
      for each( var obj:Object in myObjects )
           obj.clicked = false;

      var targetObj:Object = event.currentTarget;
      targetObj.clicked = true;

      myObjectsAction(); 
}

protected function myObjectsAction():void
{
     for each( var obj:Object in myObjects )
         if( !obj.clicked )
             doWhatever( obj );
}
```